# Comparison of two variables, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently developing a system in which the main function of it is to assess a user inputted variable, and a pre-stored variable and determine if they are the same or not, if they are, the user passes and if not, the user fails.

Currently the code I have is only outputting "Failed", even though the test data I have put in the system should show the results as having passed. The code I have is below. Only the bottom three divs actually link to the problem at hand, but I have included the entire section for reference.

```
<?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
    <div id="account-id">
        <?php echo $row->accountid;
            $account = $row->accountid; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="assignment-title">
        <?php echo $row->assignmentname;
            $name = $row->assignmentname; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="assignment">
        <?php echo $row->assignment;
            $code = $row->assignment; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="assignment">
        <?php
            $variable = $row->assignment;
            $output = eval($variable); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="assignment">
        <?php echo $row->expectedoutcome;
        $test = $row->expectedoutcome; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="assignment">
        <?php
            if(strcmp($output, $test) == 0) {
                echo "Passed"; 
                } else {
                echo "Failed"; } ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[This image shows the schema for the relating database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CaGe.png)

[This is an image of the data within the table itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzeaV.png)

Comment: As an aside, having Multiple duplicate ID's defeats the purpose of having ID's in your HTML... They are meant to be Unique. Do you mean to use class instead of id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So taking a cut down version of your code, I came up with something to play with...

```
<?php
// Simulate DB data - just one row for now
$results = array(
    (object)array(
        'account_id'       => 1,
        'assignment_name'  => 'assignment_1',
        'assignment'       => 'echo "hi";',
        'expected_outcome' => 'hi',
    )
);

// Make sure it looks ok
var_dump($results);

// Perform the test
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $variable = $row->assignment;
    echo $variable;

    // Start Buffering
    ob_start();
    eval($variable);          // This needs to be buffered
    $output = ob_get_clean(); // Get the output and clean the buffer

    $expected_answer = $row->expected_outcome;

    // Take a look at the output
    echo '<br> Output = ';
    echo $output;
    echo '<br> Expected Answer = ';
    echo $expected_answer;
    echo '<br>';

    // Perform the comparison  
    if (strcmp($output, $expected_answer) == 0) {
        echo "Passed";
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
```

It appears that you need to buffer the output from the eval as it needs to "run" and you need to capture the result. You cannot simply assign it to a variable.

You can put this into another test page to run it locally as a guide.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This should be more helpful.

Comment: I would be a little concerned though as to what "code" you are letting folks run. As you are using a database and have connected to it etc... someone could go breaking things on you with mysqli commands or whichever db you use, just to name a for instance... As the Docs say, eval is potentially dangerous in the wrong hands so you might want to add in some filtering / pre-checks. So please keep that in mind.

Comment: I just set this all up this morning, it works a charm, thanks very much. I understand the dangers of using eval() so I will be adding some filtering, thanks for all your help.